# Extracting key phrases from a short fragment

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

While there are tons of information on how to extract keywords/phrases from documents, I could not find any technique on how to extract key phrases from fragments (not necessarily sentences). Here are some examples:

- Art Museums and galleries in China -> Museums and galleries Naval
- Battles Of The Russo-Japanese War -> Naval Battles, The       Russo-Japanese War

One could suggest to simply use NLP toolkit and parse the tree and extract the noun phrases. I wonder if there are any better approaches.

Answer (score 2):

The approach depends on what kind of phrases or keywords you want to extract.

If the type of phrase is well-defined, the best way might be to parse the fragments and then extract from the parse tree with a few rules. As long as the fragments are proper English, parsers should process them with about the same quality as full sentences.

More generally, you could also approach this problem as a machine learning problem. If you have enough data, i.e. pairs of fragments and what should be extracted, you can use that to train a model. Common approaches would be

- [sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling) - marking for each token if it should be kept or dropped, using [CRFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) or [RNNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_neural_network)
- [sequence-to-sequence models](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/sequence-to-sequence-model-introduction-and-concepts-44d9b41cd42d) - encoding the input sequence and then generating a new, shorter output, using a combinations of two RNNs

In the NLP literature, you could look for sentence compression / summarization. A recent paper that first proposed the second approach listed above is:

- [A Neural Attention Model for Abstractive Sentence Summarization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.00685.pdf) - Rush et al. 2015